# How to use a socks5 proxy with authentication via selenium 4, Python and Firefox (options)

Tags: python, firefox, proxy, selenium4, socks5

I searched a lot, this came up many times over the past decade, but nothing addressing the problem or with the latest version of Selenium + Python (that I can find)

If I set up a socks5 proxy server (using Ubuntu 22.04 and Dante), I can forward my requests through it using Selenium 4 and Firefox Options like so:

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
PROXYaddr = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY'
PROXY_IP, PROXY_PORT = PROXYaddr.split(':')

options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', PROXY_IP)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', int(PROXY_PORT))

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Now this works. The problem comes in if the socks5 proxy requires a username and password authentication.

How can I add username and password auth for this socks5 proxy in Selenium 4 with Firefox?

I am looking for a solution that does not require installing extra extensions, or working with a UI as this code runs in headless mode on a server.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Firefox does not accept user/password auth for socks5 proxy *at this time*, see: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1872

The bug/feature is being tracked here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1395886

Selenium is aware of this issue here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7911

For now the solution I've used as an alternative is to use no authentication on my proxy and then use `ufw` on the server to block all IPs except for the designated ones.